# Merging two dataframes using Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have 2 DF to merge:

DF1 --> contains Stocks

```
Plant   Art_nr    Tot
A        X         5
B        Y         4
```

DF2  --Z contains open delivery

```
Plant    Art_nr   Tot
A        X        1
C        Z        3
```

I would like to obtain a DF3 where for each combination of Plant and Art_nr: 
- if there is a match between DF1.Plant&Art_nr and DF2.Plant&Art_nr I get the difference between DF1 and DF2
- if there is no match between DF1.Plant&Art_nr and DF2.Plant&Art_nr I keep the original values from DF1 and DF2

DF3 -->

```
Plant    Art_nr   Total
A        X        4
B        Y        4
C        Z        3
```

I created a "Concat" field in DF1 and DF2 to concatenate Plant and Art_nr and I tried with a full join + when + otherwise but I can't find the correct syntax

```
DF1.join(DF2, ["Concat"],"full").withColumn("Total",when(DF1.Concat.isin(DF2.Concat)), DF1.Tot - DF2.Tot).otherwise(when(not(DF1.Concat.isin(DF2.Concat)), DF1.Tot)).show()
```

Any suggestions about alternative functions I could use, or how to correctly use those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join both dataframes and then perform `case (If-Else)` expression or  `coalesce` function.

This could be done in multiple ways, here are few examples.

**Option1:** Use `coalesce` function as alternative of `CASE-WHEN-NULL`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, lit,abs

cond = [df1.Plant == df2.Plant, df1.Art_nr == df2.Art_nr]

df1.join(df2,cond,'full')  \
.select(coalesce(df1.Plant,df2.Plant).alias('Plant')
       ,coalesce(df1.Art_nr,df2.Art_nr).alias('Art_nr')
       ,abs(coalesce(df1.Tot,lit(0)) - coalesce(df2.Tot,lit(0))).alias('Tot')
       ).show()
```

**Option2:** Use `case` expression within `selectExpr()`

```
cond = [df1.Plant == df2.Plant, df1.Art_nr == df2.Art_nr]

df1.alias('a').join(df2.alias('b'),cond,'full')  \
.selectExpr("CASE WHEN a.Plant IS NULL THEN b.Plant ELSE a.Plant END AS Plant",
            "CASE WHEN a.Art_nr IS NULL THEN b.Art_nr ELSE a.Art_nr END AS Art_nr",
            "abs(coalesce(a.Tot,0) - coalesce(b.Tot,0))  AS Tot") \
.show()

#+-----+------+---+
#|Plant|Art_nr|Tot|
#+-----+------+---+
#|    A|     X|  4|
#|    B|     Y|  4|
#|    C|     Z|  3|
#+-----+------+---+
```

**Option3:** Use `when().otherwise()`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when,coalesce, lit,abs

cond = [df1.Plant == df2.Plant, df1.Art_nr == df2.Art_nr]

df1.join(df2,cond,'full')  \
.select(when(df1.Plant.isNull(),df2.Plant).otherwise(df1.Plant).alias('Plant')
       ,when(df1.Art_nr.isNull(),df2.Art_nr).otherwise(df1.Art_nr).alias('Art_nr')
       ,abs(coalesce(df1.Tot,lit(0)) - coalesce(df2.Tot,lit(0))).alias('Tot')
       ).show()
```

**Output:**

```
#+-----+------+---+
#|Plant|Art_nr|Tot|
#+-----+------+---+
#|    A|     X|  4|
#|    B|     Y|  4|
#|    C|     Z|  3|
#+-----+------+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Udf, seems verbose but gives more clarity

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, array

def score(arr):
    if arr[0] is None:
        return int(arr[1])
    elif arr[1] is None:
        return int(arr[0])
    return (int(arr[0])-int(arr[1]))

udf_final = udf(lambda arr: score(arr), IntegerType())

DF1.join(DF2, cond, "full").withColumn("final_score",udf_final(array("Tot","Total")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do a union with a groupBy and some reformatting to avoid using UDFs and without large blocks of code.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

DF3 = DF1.union(DF2.withColumn("Tot", col("Tot") * (-1)))
DF3 = DF3.groupBy("Plant", "Art_nr").agg(sum("Tot").alias("Tot"))
DF3 = DF3.withColumn("Tot", abs(col("Tot")))
```

I'm not 100% sure if there are no side effects I wasn't considering and if it fits your needs.

Comment: If you have really big Datasets, you really should try to avoid joining and UDFs. UDFs especially if you write them in python and not in scala.